# Casting string name of a instance to the instance

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a string value in which is a name of a existing instance of a class. Is any method how to get back the instance from the string?

For example:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
string nameOfInstance = "checkBox";
```

And now I would like to get the `CheckBox` instance `checkBox` only according to the `nameOfInstance` variable.

Comment: Is it the variable name? A property of something else? Just the type name? ... Give us some code.

Comment: The instance itself doesn't have a name. Variables, fields and properties that point to it have names. If you've got the name of one of those, you may be able to use reflection to retrieve the instance. But it's messy, and I would advise you to think about a different solution. You can probably solve your problem with a `Dictionary`, for example.

Comment: You might want to broaden your question to include why you want to do this. Cause it seems you might be on the wrong track...

Comment: Thank you for your idea with `Dictionary`, I see it now more clear.

Comment: Use (CheckBox)this.Controls["checkBox"].  Assuming you did everything else right, the snippet sucks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create new instances from a type:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedClassName, true);
object[] arguments = new object[]{};
object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type, arguments);
```

You can get the name space with :

```
string namespace = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace;
```

If you are looking for a way to get existing instances, create a Dictionary(,) and put the references you need to be able to look up in there.